# passing object from one package to next in golang

Tags: go

From github, https://github.com/CyCoreSystems/ari/blob/master/_examples/stasisStart/main.go

I am looking at below initiation and object gets saved to cl and later used to create handlefun..   all in same main body.. IF i want to break this up and put handlefunc in another package, how can I pass cl to it?

```
cl, err := native.Connect(&native.Options{
        Application:  "test",
        Username:     "asterisk",
        Password:     "abc123",
        URL:          "http://localhost:8088/ari",
        WebsocketURL: "ws://localhost:8088/ari/events",
    })
```

Later, this passed

```
http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // make call
        log.Info("Make sample call")
        h, err := createCall(cl)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("Failed to create call", "error", err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadGateway)
            w.Write([]byte("Failed to create call: " + err.Error()))
            return
        }

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(h.ID()))
    }))
```

Comment: You make a function, or method in the package which accepts that type. Can you explain what problem you're having doing this?

Comment: still newbie.. so I guess I cannot wrap my heads around but.. I am looking at it

Comment: I would appreciate it if you give me some guideline @jimB

Comment: We need to understand _what is the problem_ to begin with. Presently your question does not state any problem (clearly, at least). May be expand on what do you mean by "later"? Later in the same code file? If yes, then what the perceived problem is? What happens if the HTTP handler function is moved into a package separate from the one which created `cl`?

Comment: github code shows this thing running in inside of main and everything works fine.  Handler's are called from same main with the object cl.    I want to separate the function of handler's and put it into another package. I just cannot get my heads around on how to pass that "CL" to new package which will handle handlers @kostix

Comment: now trying to understand this guy  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050754/pass-object-to-struct-in-other-package     This is exactly my question but this is not clear enough for me

Comment: I think your problem may be "Pass object to struct in other package" isn't the correct problem statement. Forgot about how to do that, it's almost meaninglessly trivial; figure out what the actual problem you want to solve is and it will make more sense.

Comment: I'm with @JimB on this. Once, you have "a handler" which holds the required state (`cl`), the question basically depends on what will be contained in that another package—that is, what exported functions will it have, and which one will accept the handler. The question of using an exported API of a package is indeed largely orthogonal to the question being discussed. Also: do you really mean package in the Go sense and not just another source code file? (These are different concepts in Go.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How `cl` is "passed to" the handler function

Ah OK, I'm going to make a sheer guess and propose you got tripped by too many concepts mixed in a small blob of code.

The second argument to that `http.Handle()` is the so-called "function literal"—a definition of a function "on the spot", as opposed to defining it "the normal way like" `func some_name(list_of_args) body`. Function literals in Go are "closures", which means they "capture" any variables from available outer lexical scopes, which their bodies refer to by their names. The function literal in your example refers to `cl` and so it "closes over" that variable.

We could "unwrap" that code to look a bit more understandable:

```golang
cl, err := native.Connect(...)

handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  h, err := createCall(cl)
  ...
}

http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(handler))
```

Does it look more sensible now?

Whatever got assigned the variable `handler` is a function value which closes over the variable `cl`.

#### What you can do about it?

We could *try* rewrite this to be even more simple:

```golang
cl, err := native.Connect(...)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  h, err := createCall(cl) // Oops, this won't compile
  ...
}

http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(handler))
```

But this code won't compile as regular functions cannot refer to variables in the lexical scopes which enclose the function's definiton (let's not digress about why is that).

So, what can you do about this?

You cannot just add another argument to the argument list of `handle` because it must have certain signature, which is [`net/http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) but let's think what do you usually do when you want a function to operate on some state *attached* to it?
Right, you turn the function into a method on some data type.

So, let's just do that:

```golang
type myHander struct {
  cl native.Client // I have no idea which type native.Connect returns...
}

func (*mh myHandler) handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  h, err := createCall(mh.cl)
  ...
}
```

We can now pass it to the code which sets up stuff:

```golang
mh := myHandler{
  cl: cl,
}
http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(mh.handle))
```

#### A better approach

But we can do better if we RTFM (hint!):
the docs on `net/http.HandlerFunc` say:

> The `HandlerFunc` type is an adapter to allow the use of ordinary functions as HTTP handlers.

So if we poke around the docs to see what a "HTTP handler" is, we arrive at [`net/http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) which is an interface type, and this interface can be satisfied by any data type which has a method `ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)`.
Do you see any resemblance with `myHandler.handle`?  Right.

So our type can be turned into

```golang
type myHander struct {
  cl native.Client // I have no idea which type native.Connect returns...
}

func (*mh myHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  h, err := createCall(mh.cl)
  ...
}
```

and then we can do just

```golang
mh := myHandler{
  cl: cl,
}
http.Handle("/", &mh)
```

[Further reading](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25).

Comment: Will this work even if handler is on another package @kostix

Comment: @user3502374, may I urge you to stop being obsessed with this idea, please? ;-) My answer is the solution which allows creating "a handler" which encapsulates the result of a call to `native.Connect`. Whatever you do with an instance of what I named `myHandler`, is up to you. _If/when_ you will have troubles "passing it to another package", whatever that means, please come back with a different, concrete, question. Also please at least complete [The Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org) before asking. Thanks.

Comment: @user3502374, I mean, right now it looks like you're bashing against a problem without first trying to become familiar with key language concepts. That may be OK in itself but SO is about learning stuff; if you just need to get s_it done, just hire a freelancer rather than make people spend time trying to help you.

Comment: fair enough @kostix

Answer (score 0):

You can extract handler code into a separate factory function:

```
func MakeHandler(cl *Conn) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // make call
        log.Info("Make sample call")
        h, err := createCall(cl)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("Failed to create call", "error", err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadGateway)
            w.Write([]byte("Failed to create call: " + err.Error()))
            return
        }

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(h.ID()))
    })  
}
```

And then use it in your original scope.

```
http.Handle("/", otherpkg.MakeHandler(cl))
```